# How do I get codec list supported by android device with react-native?

Tags: android, react-native, ffmpeg, codec, encoder

I'm making a video converter app using react-native and want to compress videos problem arrives, like video downloaded from youtube in 4k are av1 encoded the device that does not have av1 hardware accelerated encoder or simply software based av1 encoder won't be able to convert, so I want to tell user this prior to conversion

For this I want list of codec supported by user's device so that I can provide a good user experience

I searched for codec lists for react native but not found anything

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this with native modules
i am giving link for reference
[ref](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaCodecInfo.html)